# Как можно сократить метод

Tags: java, массивы, freemarker

```
public List<Integer> getIndexes(User[] users) {
    List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<>();
    
    for (User user : users) {
        indexes.add(user.getId());
    }
    
    return indexes;
}
```

можно-ли сократить этот метод в одну строчку? может нужно использовать класс `Arrays`, но я далёк от него.

Если ещё напишите как это сделать во freemarker, без использования доп метода java, буду весьма благодарен

Comment: Вопрос про freemarker вынесите в отдельный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public List<Integer> getIndexes(User[] users) {
    return Arrays.stream(users).map(User::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: @Nannik рядом с ответом еще галочку можно поставить, чтобы выбрать как ответ)

Comment: Не дало сделать сразу, я и забыл